# Strange behavior of the Pattern with a Paclet

Tags: pattern-matching

I get the data from the file PacletInfo.m and I want to process them using a Pattern. For example, let's try to get the context.

```
paclet = Paclet[
   Name -> "PacletName", 
   Extensions -> {{"Kernel", Context -> "ContextName`"}}
];

getContext[Paclet[
    ___, 
    Extensions -> {___, {"Kernel", ___, Context -> name_String, ___}, ___}, 
    ___
]] := name

getContext[paclet]

(* "ContextName`" *)
```

This is worked. Now I want to create a separate definition for the Pattern:

```
pacletPattern[context_Pattern] := 
Paclet[
    ___, 
    Extensions -> {{"Kernel", ___, Context -> context, ___}},
    ___
];
```

Now you can define the function in this way:

```
getContext2[pacletPattern[context_String]] := context
```

It works again. But it's unclear why this does not work without defining functions:

```
pacletPattern[context_String]
```

> ```
> ReplaceAll::reps: {___,Extensions->    
> {{Kernel,___,Context->context_String,___}},___} is neither a list
> of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for 
> replacing.
>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {___,Extensions->
> {{Kernel,___,Context->context_String,___}},___} is neither a list of 
> replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for 
> replacing.
> ```

Comment: Are you sure you mean to force the Head `Pattern` with `context_Pattern`?

Comment: This is just an example. But in general, yes. I want to use functions that return different patterns depending on the arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problems come from the fact that `Paclet` has associated definitions, including formatting code, which is triggered by your example.

I am also very skeptical about your way of trying to parse this information. What if `Extensions` is present as `"Extensions"` instead?  What if someone used the undocumented short form `E`? Etc.

**Just do not do this.**  Dealing with paclets should be done with utmost care because they are undocumented, and not designed for end users.  What you are doing is asking for trouble.  I strongly suggest you stick to the API.

**Use the `PacletInformation` function:**

```
rules = PacletInformation["/path/to/PacletInfo.m"]
```

This gives you a rule list form which you can get the information conveniently.

```
Lookup[rules, "Context"]
```

If you want a `Paclet` expression, use the `CreatePaclet` function.  Comments in the paclet manager source say:

> ALL reading of `PacletInfo.m` files into Mathematica should be done by
>   this function.    The trick we use is to read the files in such a way
>   that Paclet and the other symbols (`Name`, `Version`,    etc.) are created
>   in a private context. Then we turn them into strings, except for
>   Paclet. Thus, this function returns an expression like  `{Paclet["Name"->"foo", "Version"->"1.0", ...]}` where there are no
>   symbols, only strings,    except for System symbols like `True`, `False`,
>   `All`.

Thus you should use

```
paclet = CreatePaclet["/path/to/PacletInfo.m"]
```

This will verify the contents of the file and create a consistent `Paclet` expression.  Then you can e.g.

```
paclet["Name"]
```

to get the name or

```
paclet["Extensions"]
```

to get the extensions.

However, the most convenient way would still be `PacletInformation[paclet]`, so why not use that function directly on the `PacletInfo.m` file?

Note that the `Paclet` expression you are trying to work with is not a valid one.  `Name` should be `"Name"` instead, otherwise things won't work.  If you `Get` the `PacletInfo.m` directly, then you will not only end up with an invalid `Paclet` expression, but also create several symbols (like `Name`).  This is probably undesirable.

Comment: Yep, it breaks trying to format `Paclet[...]`, a quick fix would be e.g. `Verbatim[Paclet][___,...`.

Comment: @Kuba It would still not be the correct way to deal with a `PacletInfo.m` ...

Comment: That is why I didn't answer after you.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Many thanks! `PacletInformation` is what suits me. I realized that this was an wrong method, but the problem was that the functions of PacletManager were not documented

Comment: @KirillBelov Yes, that makes it pretty difficult, unfortunately.  There is some documentation within the source files.  It's in SystemFiles/Autoload.